# add value to string with an an separate comma

Tags: php

I want to add a value to string 14 times with a separate comma ",".

```
$result = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
    $result += $i . ",";

}

echo $result;
```

But I keep getting an error. Can someone help me?

I want to output this `"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14" (string)` from a variable.

Comment: Replace `+=` with `.=`

Comment: _“But I keep getting an error.”_ - next time, please mention _what_ error you get, not just _that_ you get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#:%7E:text=String%20Operators%20%C2%B6&text=The%20first%20is%20the%20concatenation,argument%20on%20the%20left%20side.)

```
$result .= "," .$i;
```

Your code needs some enhancements as well:

```
<?php

$result = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {//start with 1 otherwise 2 Zero will come
   //put , concatenation first to overcome missing , in beginning and extra , at the end
   $result .= ",".$i;
}

echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/HD2mZ

Note:- What you actually did is trying to add the numbers. And due `. ","` it is giving you Warning(Warning: A non-numeric value encountered).And finally adding all numbers anyhow (105).

Answer (score 3):

Or just:

```
echo implode(',', range(0, 14));
```